# Run scala compiler with options from play console

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to pass options to the scala compiler from within play.

I got: `[warn] there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found`

So I tried using `compile -feature` but got:

```
$ compile -feature
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] compile -feature
[error]
```

What is the proper way to pass options to the compiler in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add scalac options in the `project/Build.scala` file.

Open this file and add your own project settings into the Play project object at the bottom of the file. For example:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here   
    scalacOptions += "-feature" 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ set scalacOptions += "-feature"
$ compile
```

Comment: You can add that similar line to build.sbt as well as
`scalacOptions += "-feature"`. In my case, it's warning about the use of `-language:implicitConversions`.